# Angular 2 : Call component dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, components, angular2-template

I build an Ionic 2 app so I use Angular 2. I want to call some component dynamically. I want to know if it's possible to write somethink like this :

```
<my-comp-[VAR]><my-comp-[VAR]/>
```

For example in a ts file :

```
component: string = 'home';
```

And in my html file :

```
<my-comp-{{component}}><my-comp-{{component}}/>
```

What is the best way to do somethink like that ?

Comment: No, that's not possible, because you need to compile it. Read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e), specifically `Creating components on the fly` section

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Refer to this [**medium post**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/load-modal-component-dynamically-in-angular-5fda8e1dc3e7)